# Azure Service bus to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I am running into issues while trying to run a WCF REST service that will connect to an Azure Service bus.  My web.config contains the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="helloSB.SomeService">
<endpoint contract="helloSB.ISomeService"
binding="webHttpRelayBinding"
address = "" />
<host>
<baseAddresses>
<add baseAddress="http://localhost:7200/mySB/helloSB.SomeService/" />
</baseAddresses>
</host>
```

Whenever I try to send a message to WCF, I receive:
    The service /mySB/SomeService.svc cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception is : Unable to reach localhost via TCP (9351, 9352) or HTTP (80,443).

Why can't I use a non-standard port?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these are related to some port issues. The below link provides additional details on troubleshooting steps.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2055.troubleshooting-connectivity-issues-in-the-azure-appfabric-service-bus.aspx